# Command Prompt freezing after pressing enter, invalid loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I am currently making a program that allows you to choose 1 of 4 options, and in order to execute this properly, I have to use a loop. The point of this simple program is to allow the user to select 1 of 4 choices:

1 - Set percent to avg by
2 - Enter grade (and take the avg of those grades entered)
3 - Get average (I'm assuming the grade avg and the percent avg entered)
4 - Quit

At the moment, I get no compile errors and am able to run the program. Whenever I type 1 and press enter, for some reason the number enters but then it's just a blank space, and I have to press CTRL-C to unfreeze it. I also do not know how to get the " while ( choice != 1); " line to execute properly.

I need to get the program to loop, allowing the user to do every option as many times as they want until they press 4 to quit, so I am using a sentinel-controlled loop. Here is my code, and I am a beginner so I may not have the whole "Loop" process down yet. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseThree
{
public static void main ( String[] argsv )
{

    float percent = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    double totalAvg = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double gradeAvg = 0;

    int gradeCounter = 0;
    int quit;
    int choice;
    int choiceOne;


    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println( "Please choose one of the following: \n 1 - Set percentage of total for new grades \n 2 - Enter new grades \n 3 - Get average \n 4 - Quit ");
        choice = input.nextInt();


    while ( choice != 4 );

        switch ( choice )
        {

            case 1: 

            if( choice == 1 ) {     
                System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by" );
                percent = input.nextFloat();

            break;
            }

            case 2:

            if ( choice == 2 ) {
                System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
                grade = input.nextDouble();
                total = total + grade;
                gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
                gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;
            break;      
            }



            case 3:

            if ( choice == 3 ) {
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to get the average" );
                totalAvg = totalAvg + percent * grade;
                totalAvg = input.nextDouble();          
            break;
            }


            default: 

            if ( choice == 4 ){
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to quit" );
                quit = input.nextInt();
            break; 
            }



        }
```

Comment: `if( choice != 4 || choice == 4 )` - This is always `true` :/

Comment: Oh I see! Because any choice != 4 would also make 1, 2, or 3 count as != 4

Comment: Furthermore, when you `switch(choice)`, there is no need for the `if` after that. Since.. you `switch(choice)` already did that.

Comment: I don't understand why whenever I enter let's say a 1, it doesn't execute the code for Case 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even know where to start... there are multiple errors in your code:

```
while ( choice != 4 );
```

remove the semi-colon and wrap your `switch` inside `{` `}`

```
if ( choice == 1 )
```

there is no need to place an if statement inside a `case`, it's redundant

```
if ( choice != 4 || choice == 4 ){
```

this is always true and, as already said, the `if` is redundant in a `case` code block

```
case 1: 

if ( choice == 1 ) {        
    System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by" );
    percent = input.nextFloat();

}
```

at the end of each `case` code block you need to place a `break;` statement

Comment: Thank you! I also have another question, whenever you press 1 and you enter the percentage, how would I go back to the menu with the 4 options? Right now it just loops "Enter a percentage to multiply by"

Comment: That happens because the value of your `choice` variable never changes, so you enter into an infinite loop where the `choice` variable is always equal to 1... I think you should do a little rework to your code's logic

Comment: I'm thinking I can do a counter-controlled loop so It'll know once they enter a percentage, then it can go back to the menu after entering it once since that's all they will be doing.

Answer (score 1):

After each case you should put a "break" statement.

```
    case 1: 

        if ( choice == 1 ) {        
            System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by" );
            percent = input.nextFloat();
```

So instead put:

```
    case 1: 

        if ( choice == 1 ) {        
            System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by" );
            percent = input.nextFloat();
            break;
```

That is the only problem I see. If you have any other questions comment this answer.

Comment: Remove that `if` please, it's redundant.

Comment: I changed it accordingly, althought I previously had break statements and deleted them to see if it'd fix the problem (Idk XD) 

But the problem still exists, even when I deleted the if statements, when I run the program, Enter a number, it shows the number then shows a blank space and I have to press Control-C to exit the program.

Comment: I fixed it by putting a { before the switch!